# I want to subtract an integer from an Integer array with one number in it in Java

Tags: java, arrays

So here is what I'm trying to do:

```
    final int[] example = {1};
```

Over the course of a little bit this value increases to over 50. Here is my problem:

```
    example[0] - 50;
```

It gives this error:

```
    Syntax error on token "-", invalid AssignmentOperator
```

I have tried so many things and nothing has worked. I've scoured the internet trying to find a solution and haven't. Please, someone help me with this.

EDIT: I have another problem. Let's say example = 67. When I do:

```
    example[0] -= 50;
```

It sets the number to 0, and not to 67 - 50.

Comment: `example[0] -= 50;`

Comment: The 2nd part looks like a new question. Consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235) the answer provided

Comment: How on earth does the expression in your EDIT set the value to 0?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it does. I am very confused.

Comment: Could you please provide the code where it is set to 0? I mean all of it.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it; tiny stupid bug in my code. Thank you everyone who answered and sorry if I wasted your time.

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
example[0] -= 50;
```

Just using `example[0] - 50;` does nothing, doesn't assign the result of the calculation to anything. So I use `x -= y;`, which expands to `x = x - y;`, so you have the calculation which is assigned back to the original variable (in your case, `example[0]`).

Comment: Since OP sounds like a complete beginner, you may want to explain that this is a short form for a regular assignment.

Comment: I had done that and for some reason it didn't work, but now it does. I'm pretty confused. Well, thank you!

Comment: @PM77-1 I was in the process of editing it into my answer :)